# Ruby on Rails: How to model recurring times (weekly activities)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database-design, data-modeling

In my Ruby on Rails application, I have a "Group" model that has weekly recurring "activities". Some activities occur only one day a week (Friday at 6:00pm) while some occur multiple times a week (Mon-Fri at 8:00am, or Tues/Thurs at 10:00am).

I am having trouble trying to figure out how to model this data, and how to use Rails to create a form to create/update the data. Do I create an "Activities" table that has a datetime field? Or do I separate the day of the week from the time of day into two separate fields? What about the activities that occur multiple times a week?

Any ideas or advice would be appreciated. Also, I would appreciate knowing if you know of a Gem that helps with this so I don't have to re-invent the wheel.

**Update:**

For Example, if I needed to display something like this:

#### Special Group A's Activities

- Monday at 10pm - Football
- Tues/Thurs at 8am - Tennis

#### Special Group B's Activities

- Monday-Friday at 12pm - Lunch
- Saturday at 8am - Breakfast
- Sunday at 6pm - Dinner

What steps would I need to take in order to model and display this data, using Ruby on Rails?

Answer (score 2):

Models
group.rb

```
class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_presence_of :name
  has_many :activities, :through => :group_activity
end

activity.rb
class Activity < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_presence_of :name
  belongs_to :group
  has_many :occurances, :through => :activity_occurance
end

occurance.rb
class Activity < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_presence_of :date
  belongs_to :activity
end
```

Migrations (separate or all together)
add_everything.rb

```
class AddEverything < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    create_table :groups, :force => true do |t|
      t.string  :name
      t.timestamps
    end
    create_table :group_activity, :force => true do |t|
      t.integer  :group_id, :activity_id
      t.timestamps
    end
    create_table :activities, :force => true do |t|
      t.string  :name
      t.timestamps
    end
    create_table :activity_occurance, :force => true do |t|
      t.integer  :activity_id, :occurance_id
      t.timestamps
    end
    create_table :occurance, :force => true do |t|
      t.datetime  :date
      t.timestamps
    end
  end

  def self.down
    drop_table :groups
    drop_table :activities
    drop_table :occurances
    drop_table :group_activity
    drop_table :activity_occurance
  end
end
```

That take's care of your model work. In your groups _form view I would add your associated group name, and fields_for for your activity name and fields_for occurance. In your occurance, use this handy jQuery datetime picker that is an extension off of the jQuery date picker, to populate your occurance field:

http://puna.net.nz/timepicker.htm

You should also have separate views to manage activities separately with it's own respective form. In your show page displaying other fields is pretty standard, but for the occurances you can have something like (haml syntax):

```
= @group.name
- for activity in @group.activities
  = activity.name
  - for occurance in activity.occurances
    = occurance.date.strftime("%A at %r")
```

Hope this at least gets you started. You can add additional logic for checking activity.occurances.size to format accordingly if you want to display something day1/day2/day3

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/jimweirich/texp Jim Weirich's Temporal expressions library is an excellent resource for querying these sorts of things in ruby.

If you don't need to query this set other than looking at all of them in batch, then just serializing that datastructure would probably work for you.

But in the end you'll probably just use a `has_many :occurances` where occurances start off as date_time homebaked-recurrence-pattern pairs and iterate from there depending on what feature set you need.

Answer (score 0):

If you think it straight, there is a great number of possibilites for you to represent and persist diverse date and time formats and intervals on a database, also you probably are going to change it to add some options to users or to remove options accordingly to the growth of your website.

I would go with creating two fields like "date_start" and "date_end", and one string field containing a code that represents the frequency. Something like 3 chars per code, first can be M for monthly, W weekly; second can be F for first, L for last; third char can be a number for a specific number of the week, F for friday.

The point here is that you can (encode and) decode that programatically so if you add features you won't have to recreate your database relations.

Answer (score 0):

In the same way a group can have multiple activities, I think an activity can have multiple occurances. I would suggest trying to model your database that way, with a occurance table.

Regarding the form, what about a "master - detail" form with activity as the master, and occurance as the detail?